# Pig: Count frequency of multiple columns

Tags: apache-pig

I want to calculate the frequency of 2 field-combinations in pig:

```
------ y1 has the fields -----
a1 = GROUP y1 BY (user_id, tweet_created_at);
a2 = FOREACH a1 GENERATE group AS (user_id, tweet_created_at), COUNT(y1) AS number_of_replies_by_user;
a3 = FOREACH a2 GENERATE user_id, tweet_created_at, number_of_replies_by_user;
a4 = JOIN y1 BY (user_id, tweet_created_at) LEFT OUTER, a3 BY (user_id, tweet_created_at);
```

In the above, I want to calculate the frequency of the (`user_id, tweet_created_at`) field combination.

The line `a2 = FOREACH a1 GENERATE group AS (user_id, tweet_created_at), COUNT(y1) AS number_of_replies_by_user;` gives an error: `Incompatable schema: left is "user_id:NULL,tweet_created_at:NULL", right is "group:tuple(user_id:bytearray,tweet_created_at:bytearray)"`

I tried without the brackets: `a2 = FOREACH a1 GENERATE group AS user_id, tweet_created_at, COUNT(y1) AS number_of_replies_by_user;`

I get another error:

```
Invalid field projection. Projected field [tweet_created_at] does not exist in schema:..................
```

Is that a syntax error or an issue with my data?
What is the right way if it a syntax error?

**In short:** I want to calculate the number of replies a user gave at the time of every tweet posted. (If he posted 2 tweets on the same day, he might have reply count 10 at the time of first tweet and 15 at the time of second). I guess if I don't group by `tweet_created_at`, the reply count will be a constant at all times which is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FLATTEN](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Flatten+Operator) on the group to unnest the tuple into the fields

```
a2 = FOREACH a1 GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (user_id, tweet_created_at), COUNT(y1) AS number_of_replies_by_user;
```